# Configuring Postgresql as a service on OpenShift v3

Tags: postgresql, tcp, openshift, router

I'm trying to configure a Postgresql pod on OpenShift 3 for external access and I'm unable to expose it to the outside world. I have created a route, but it is not responding to TCP on port 5423 whenever I try to connect to the host over the internet.

The message I get is: "Is the server running on host "xxxxxxx.1d35.starter-us-east-1.openshiftapps.com" (xx.xx.xx.xx) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Routes can only be used to expose HTTP/HTTPS servers, or when using TLS pass through the service is terminating the secure connection and the client for the services support SNI over TLS.

For a database such as PostgreSQL you can though temporarily expose it to your local machine by using the `oc port-forward` command. You can find an interactive tutorial for how to use port forwarding in the OpenShift interactive learning portal at:

- https://learn.openshift.com/

In OpenShift Online there is no way to expose a database service such as PostgreSQL permanently outside of the cluster. This is because exposing it would require admin access, which you don't have with OpenShift Online.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!